# UserControl matching the size of a Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, listbox

My application is written in WPF. I have a Window with initial `Width = 400`. Within that Window I have a DockPanel with a StackPanel containing a custom UserControl called `ElementsPanel`.

Here is the code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Adiastemo2.EditWindow" ... Height="500" Width="400" x:Name="view2" ... >
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="70" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Beige">
            <local:ElementsPanel/>
        </StackPanel> ...
```

The ElementsPanel control consists of a StackPanel with a `ListBox`. The ListBox's ItemsPanel is templated with a simple ScrollViewer and an ItemsPresenter.

Here is the code again:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Adiastemo2.ElementsPanel" ...
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="70">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20" >
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="BlanchedAlmond"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListBox.Template>
        ... <!-- Some test content comprising several 50x50 Buttons -->
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I'd like my ElementsPanel and its content's Width to resize whenever the Window gets resized, so that horizontal scrolling was enabled if there are too many Buttons to display. Right now what I get is this:

500x400 Window: http://screenshooter.net/100101493/qiaxocp

Wider: http://screenshooter.net/100101493/utkcyel

How do I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the **`Width`** of UserControl to **`ActualWidth`** of Window:

```
<Window x:Class="Adiastemo2.EditWindow" ... Height="500"
        Width="400" x:Name="view2" ... >
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Height="70" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="Beige">
            <local:ElementsPanel Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                                 ElementName=view2}"/>
        </StackPanel> ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped when I bound the Width of the ListBox's VirtualizingStackPanel to the Width of the UserControl, too.